# Ephemeral animations in lit-element?

Tags: javascript, css, lit-element, lit

I have a fairly straightforward but ephemeral animation I'd like to do in Lit, but the how of it isn't coming together. About 12 years ago, I wrote a little jQuery "refrigerator poem" thing, you know, with the words on magnetic tiles you move around to create poems.
When you dropped a tile, little hearts and stars would shoot out from underneath it, like a "splash" of fireworks, before fading away.

[The original implementation](https://github.com/elfsternberg/fridgemagnets/blob/60f398b143316c6702c0e3bff08339f051d724e3/src/magnets.coffee#L89) (it's in Coffeescript v1, sorry) was simple: I put all the stars one z-index "under" the tile, then used jQuery animation to make them "shoot out" a small distance; at the end of the animation, the element created called `el.remove()` to remove itself from the DOM.

In my Lit implementation, I have two central Lit components: a WordBoard consists of WordTiles. Following Justin Fagnani's advice, the tile has a Drag & Drop mixin that issues a "tile-dropped" event, which the board can use to trigger the animation start.

In trying to re-write this in Lit (and YouMightNotNeedJquery), I'm stymied by how hard Lit is watching the DOM.  I want to add my elements to the Board's renderRoot, use CSS animations to "splash, then fade" the fireworks effect, and have the animation elements remove themselves from the DOM.  It should be easy, but I found that trying to use `TemplateResults` didn't work and modifying the renderRoot's innerHTML caused Lit to freak out and re-render everything.

What's the correct way to do an ephemeral animation like this using Lit?

Comment: Why Lit? There are [61 alternatives](https://webcomponents.dev/blog/all-the-ways-to-make-a-web-component/) Why did you choose this tool?